# kendo tabstrip reload on dropdownlistfor onchange function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a view in my project  it has a kendo dropdownlistfor

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.database_pk)
        .BindTo(Model.databases)
        .Name("database_pk").OptionLabel("Select one...")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "database_pk", onchange = "changeDatabase()" })
    )
```

and a kendo tabstrip

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                .Name("menu")
                .Items(items =>
                    {
                        items.Add().Text("Database Info").LoadContentFrom("DatabaseInfo", "Home", new { database_pk = Model.database_pk }).Selected(true); 
                        items.Add().Text("Tables").LoadContentFrom("TableInfo", "Table", new { database_pk = Model.database_pk }).Selected(true);
                        items.Add().Text("Entities").LoadContentFrom("EntityInfo", "Entity", new { database_pk = Model.database_pk }).Selected(true);
                    })
                .Events(events =>
                    {
                        events.Select("selectMenuTabs");
                    })
    )
```

The deal is I need my tabstrip to "reload" the selected tab if the onchange event is fired on the dropdownlist

The function for onchange is

```
function changeDatabase() {
    var selected_pk = $('#database_pk').val();
    reloadTabstrip();
}
```

and teh reload function is

```
function reloadTabstrip() {
    var tabStrip = $("#menu").data("kendoTabStrip");
    tabStrip.reload($(".item", tabStrip.element)[0]);
}
```

the reloadTabstrip function is not working and I'm having a hard time finding anything on the web to point me in the right direction.

Comment: getting any errors in console??

Comment: nope step through the jquery using the chrome dev tools and no errors pop up. IM stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved teh problem with the following jquery script

```
function reloadTabstripItem() {
    var selected_pk = $('#database_pk').val();
    var index = $("#menu").data("kendoTabStrip").select().index();
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            actionurl = "/Home/DatabaseInfo";
            break;
        case 1:
            actionurl = "/Table/TableInfo";
            break;
        case 2:
            actionurl = "/Entity/EntityInfo";
            break;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/DatabaseInfo",
        type: 'GET',
        data: { database_pk: selected_pk }
    }).done(function (html) {
        $($("#menu").data("kendoTabStrip").contentElement(0)).html(html);
    });
}
```